# Is there a way to add a plot(s) to a poster in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, png, poster

This is quite a vague and general question. Essentially I have a poster template in PDF or PNG format and there are designated sections on the poster where I will need to insert bar-charts.

I have produced the charts using ggplot2 but is there a way to scale these to size and insert them onto the poster?

I have imported the poster into RStudio using the inset_element() function but not sure this if this is the best way to do this also. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Where does the function `insert_element()` come from?

Comment: @DaveArmstrong this is part of the patchwork package